# Create a stored procedure on plugin activation

Tags: wpdb

I want to know that is it possible to fire a stored procedure once the plugin is activated?

```
//action hook for plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_func' );

//function to create stored procedure
function my_func()
{
//code goes here to create a stored procedure
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, though I would not recommend it - you would be better off having the procedure stored as SQL statements within a PHP function that you can call whenever you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I did not get that -> "he procedure stored as SQL statements within a PHP function that you can call whenever you need it". Can you explain it?

Comment: Can you tell me what your stored procedure _is_?

Comment: That is quite big. You can use simple stored procedure i.e. select * from table. I did not get how to call from php function.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, let's say you were planning on the following stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
```

Instead of actually stashing this inside MySQL, let's create a PHP function:

```
function {plugin_prefix}_get_posts() {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts" );
}
```

Now we can call this whenever we need it:

```
$posts = {plugin_prefix}_get_posts();
// Away we go!
```

I've intentionally used invalid PHP to save the future copy-pasters from themselves - **rename the function to something specific to your project!**

Comment: Thank you @TheDeadMedic for your help. I understood what you want to explain. I have one more query. My stored procedure takes 3 inputs and returns an output value. Actual I am dealing with 4 to 5 database tables. In that case also, should I create a php function like you have explained? So whenever that function will call then all those queries from php function will fire.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, on plugin activation you just need to call the relevant mysql queries via the php api as documented in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php, and remove on deactivation.

Is it smart? I am far from being a mysql guru, but it seems like @thedeadmedic is right about doing simple things like selects. Performance of such things depends on the complexity of the data and you save nothing by reducing the size of the request. Stored procedures has an advantage only if it can reduce the amount of data which travels from the DB to PHP.

Another two things to remember in the context of general plugins.

1. Stored procedures are global to the DB and not unique to a specific WP instance, therefor they need to be written carefully to both not collide with other stored procedure, and from security POV, not to leak data.
2. At the time of writing this answer there are about 7% of wordpress users that run on mysql versions that do not support them (versions older than 5.5).

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in the activation hook using `$wpdb->query()` and make sure to prefix it properly.

```
public static function activation_hook() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "
    CREATE PROCEDURE {$wpdb->prefix}STORED_PROC_NAME(param1 varchar(16))
    RETURNS varchar(16)
    BEGIN
       --do your stored proc here
       RETURN param1
    END
    ";
    $wpdb->query($sql);

}
```